# Apps did not download after vpn is connected

Tags: android, dns, google-play, vpn

I am making an application that block certain webs and application but problem is on Some devices manufacture Like Motorola and HTC (android OS nougat and oreo) apps did not download and update after VPN is Connected But Internet Work perfectly.I am using Local VPN to monitor Network Trafic. Please Help i am stuck on this stage.

**I tried all methods mention on the google**

- https://www.androidpit.com/google-play-not-working
- http://appslova.com/android-fix-error-495-in-google-play-store/
- http://techknowzone.com/how-to-solve-fix-error-code-495-in-google-play-store/

Below is the Snipped of local VPN Code

```
private void connect() {
       int i;
    isRunning=true;

    Builder builder = new Builder();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("10.0.0.");
    if (lastInt == 254) {
        i = 0;
        lastInt = 0;
    } else {
        i = lastInt;
        lastInt = i + 1;
    }
    this.localAddress = stringBuilder.append(i).toString();
    try {
        if (this.parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
            this.parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        builder.addAddress(this.localAddress, 24);
        builder.addDnsServer(dns1);
        builder.addDnsServer(dns2);
        this.parcelFileDescriptor = builder.setSession(getString(R.string.app_name)).setConfigureIntent(this.pendingIntent).establish();
        Intent intent = new Intent("STARTEDDNSCHANGER");
        intent.setAction(getPackageName() + ".STARTED_DNS_CHANGER");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    } catch (Throwable e2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Play downloads apps over HTTPS. If you are getting error 495 it suggests that the VPN is interfering with the HTTPS / TLS handshaking, and so Play won't download the apps. Possibly you don't support the cipher algorithm negotiation properly.

Comment: thanks for you answer Nick.can you further elaborate and share some useful resources  to implement  cipher algorithm negotiation ?

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my expertise